# Finding Unique Indexes in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing

How I can find all unique indexes in MongoDB?

The `db.collection.getIndexes()` function doesn't give any information about uniqueness.

Comment: Did you try? As far as I remember this information is shown (if it does exist!)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, The result does not contain any thing related to uniqeness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getIndexes()` should work:

```
db.collection.createIndex({key: 1}, {unique: true})
    
db.collection.getIndexes()

[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : { "_id" : 1 },
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : { "key" : 1 },
        "name" : "key_1",
        "unique" : true
    }
]
```

If the index is not unique then `"unique": true` is simply missing.

Comment: However, _id is unique and  ** "unique": true ** is still missing. A caveat.